# OpenCV problem with perspectiveTransform - scn + 1 and m.cols

Tags: python, opencv, geometry

I have found a perspective matrix using:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

points_src = np.single([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0]])
points_dst = np.single([[0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 2], [2, 2], [2, 0.5]])
perspective_matrix = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(points_src, points_dst)
```

Which yields the expected:

```py
>>> perspective_matrix
array([[1.5, 0. , 0.5],
       [0. , 1.5, 0.5],
       [0. , 0. , 1. ]])
```

However, when I try and transform points using perspectiveTransform:

```py
points_original = np.single([[0, 0]])
points_transformed = cv.perspectiveTransform(points_original, perspective_matrix)
```

I get the following error:

```
"error: (-215:Assertion failed) scn + 1 == m.cols in function 'cv::perspectiveTransform'"
```

I have tried padding the `points_original` coordinates with a trailing 1 (`np.single([[0, 0, 1]])`), as it looks like is done in [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gad327659ac03e5fd6894b90025e6900a7), as well as adding more points (`np.single([[0, 0], [1, 1]])` or `np.single([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])`), removing a layer of nesting in the lists (`np.single([0, 0])`, `np.single([0, 0, 0])`), etc, etc, and I can't figure out what is still going wrong. TIA.

Comment: According to the docs `src` should be "input *two-channel* or *three-channel* floating-point array". Yours is just a 2D numpy array, which is equivalent to a single channel array.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you, I had assumed channels were just the rgb values and equivalent to the final dimension in the np array - what is the difference between channel and dimension please? And how do I create a 2 or 3 channel array as appropriate, when I only want to transform the point locations?

Comment: Channels do represent the RGB components, but in order for OpenCV to map the numpy array to `cv::Mat` (the C++ class that OpenCV uses), those need to be the 3rd dimension/axis (first dimension are rows, second columns). | You can either create the properly shaped directly, by adding another level of nesting to the initial list: `np.single([[[0, 0]]])`. Or, you could `reshape` the existing array, say like `np.single([[0, 0]]).reshape(-1,1,2)` -- that means there will be as many rows as necessary (1 in this case), one entry (column) per row, and the entry will have two components.

Comment: ... (in this case the "components" are not colour intensities, as in the case of RGB, or YUV or whatever other colour format, but they represent the x and y coordinates).

Comment: @DanMašek working great now, thanks for the help! Once I have it "neatened up" I'll write up a proper answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question based on the helpful comments received from @Dan Mašek.

According to the docs, src should be:

> input two-channel or three-channel floating-point array.

In order for OpenCV to map the numpy array to cv::Mat (the C++ class that OpenCV uses), the channels (usually RGB components, but in this case coordinates) need to be the 3rd dimension/axis (first dimension are rows, second columns).

Either create the properly shaped array, by adding another level of nesting to the initial list: `np.single([[[0, 0]]])`, or reshape the existing array: `np.single([[0, 0]]).reshape(-1,1,2)`. This results in as many rows as necessary (one in this case), one column per row, and two channels per column.

TLDR:

I just required an extra layer of nesting, for example:

```
points_original = np.single([[[0, 0]]])
points_transformed = cv.perspectiveTransform(points_original, perspective_matrix)
```